# Write a number as an array of 1 and 2 which has a sum equal to that number using recursion in Python

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, python-2.7, recursion

After googling for the solution, I could not find any alternative on the web, except for C++ and Java.

I have seen questions with a given array of elements, although I do not have predefined array in my case. A program should create it by itself.

**Problem:**
I need to know how many combinations of 1 and 2 sum up to the input number.

```
INPUT     OUTPUT
1         1
3         3
5         8
```

**How to solve it?**

The program should convert an input number to arrays (array for N = 1), elements of which sum up to the input number. Then it should count the number of arrays (combinations).

**For the clarity**

N = 1 (1 combination)

```
[1]
```

N = 2 (2 combinations)

```
[1, 1]
[2]
```

N = 3 (3 combinations)

```
[1, 1, 1]
[1, 2]
[2, 1]
```

N = 4 (5 combinations)

```
[1, 1, 1, 1]
[2, 1, 1]
[1, 2, 1]
[1, 1, 2]
[2, 2]
```

etc.

Comment: P.S. I have posted a similar question recently, but it was a copy and paste of a textbook problem. I apologize SO community members.

Comment: @StephenRauch I don't think there's a single digit case for 3 if the only possible values are 1 and 2.

Comment: You said you found C++ and Java examples? Do you understand how they work at all?

Comment: @StephenRauch the single digit case exists only for N = 1. Otherwise, there are two or more arrays. I do not miss cases, only 1 and 2 can appear within any of the arrays.

Comment: Do you need to create "an" array who's sum is the given number, or "all" array's who's sum is the given number?

Comment: Do you need to find *all* of the arrays? (Do you even need to find *any* of the arrays, or do you just need to find how many there are?)

Comment: @JeremyWest there were some specific libraries tailored for those languages. I can find the alternative for the libraries in python, but the thing is I am new to python, so I want to understand recursion better. In general, there were no similar questions on SO, that is why I am asking for your perspectives.

Comment: @user2357112 how many there are! I will update the question, thank you!

Comment: @ErikBrodyDreyer I have updated the question. Thank you for some explanations on recursion. Also, I got the answer from my classmates, although I am going to work on the solution after the class.

Comment: I'd very strongly recommend going back when the time crunch is over for any assignments you get a lot of help from classmates or instructors with, and redoing them on your own, solving them a different way than the instructor or classmate showed you, just to be sure you learn what the lesson was trying to teach. It's important to not fall behind in courses like this, catching up is difficult. You sound like you're going to work on this, and that's good, I'm just trying to really drive this home.

Answer (score 1):

Use tail recursion to reduce the stack to `O (1)` space:

```
def fib(n):
  if n in [0,1]:
    return 1

  return _f(1, 1, n)

def _fib(a, b, i):
  if i == 1:
    return a

  return _f(a+b, a, i-1)

print(fib(4)) # 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Recursive solutions have two parts. They have a base case, or a simplest case, and they have a "recursive" case, or a case that is solved by first solving a simpler form of the problem.

In this problem, what is the simplest possible case, and how would you solve it?

How can you reduce the problem, and use this solution recursively on the reduced problem to then solve the original problem?

As an example, here's a recursive definition of factorial:

```
def factorial(n):
    if n <= 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return factorial(n-1) * n
```

Now, for your problem, the simplest possible form would be if you're given 0, and the solution in that case should be trivial.

For the recursive case, if take in the number n, and you call your function on some smaller number, maybe n-1 or n-2, then you could use that answer to build up the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
def combination(n):
    if n == 0 or n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return combination(n-1) + combination(n-2)

def main():
    n = input()
    print(combination(n))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: You have 2 issues with this solution:
1. it raises errors, because you are passing a string for n in the main() function
2. if you parse that n = int(input()) and run it with n = 100 your solution will run forever. That's because the time complexity of your solution is O(2^n)

Answer (score 0):

Just an example, may be this will help.

```
def get_arays(n):
    divs = [i for i in xrange(1, n/2 + 1) if not n % i]     # get divisors
    for i in divs:
        print [i]*(n/i)


get_arays(100)
```

## EX OP

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
[4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
[5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
[10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10]
[20, 20, 20, 20, 20]
[25, 25, 25, 25]
[50, 50]
```